# mysql login problem , easily login with root but not with root@localhost

Tags: mysql, linux, database, apache, unix

I am able to login with `mysql -u root -p`

but not with

`mysql -u root@localhost -p`

It says

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root@localhost'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the host to connect to.

try:

```
mysql -u root -h localhost -p
```

Comment: any way I can login with root@localhost ? An external shell is using this format , do I can not change it

Comment: from my experience `username`@`hostname` is usually for ssh, I do not know if there is a way to login as you have specified.

Comment: @RishiNiranjan change host to 127.0.0.1 and check

Answer (score -1):

Below below command:

```
mysql -u root@($hostname) -p
```

Comment: then find hostname for below command like $hostname and then put hostname in command.